# List of supported native code of Android phones

Tags: android, arm, native, android-ndk, cpu-architecture

Is there any list of Android phones and their supported native code?

For example I want to know which phones support only `armeabi` and which support `armeabi-v7a`. The latter is important because I'm doing a lot of floating-point calculation in native code.

Comment: If your question really is "are there enough `armeabi-v7a` devices to warrant creating the separate NDK `.so`?", then I think the answer is yes. I believe most of the 2010 higher-end smartphones (Nexus One on up) all use the ARM7. If you have the NDK build both `.so` files, the device will choose the right one at runtime, giving you the speed boost for floating point while not compromising compatibility with older ARM chipsets.

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually the question is, I have a native code which executes fast enough on v7a, but around the time limit on non-v7a. Some users say that they are using "Droid", "HTC Hero" and so on and got problems, I want to know whether the problem is because they don't support v7a or some other problems. Btw I'm your digital book subscriber. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I understand. If "the time limit" is the ANR limit, you might consider moving that work to an `AsyncTask` or `IntentService` or something anyway. There will still be plenty of ARM5 chips, particularly on the low end. And unless ARM7 floating point is 100x faster than ARM5 (which it could be for all I know), your UI might still be better served with the ARM7 work being done off the main application thread. If, OTOH, I am misinterpreting "the time limit", I apologize. And thanks for subscribing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another good link is:

- http://www.pdadb.net Useful
  smartphonesdatabase.

Sorry for answer two times. I can only send one link per answer.......

Comment: Just to clarify in case anyone is confused like I was... go to: `OS Database > Search Tool > Platform > Supported CPU Instruction Set(s)` to search for specific ABIs. This produces a list of operating systems instead of devices, though.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same situation before and I used this link:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapdragon_(processor)
  In this page you can find
  information for other manufacturers:
  Texas Instruments, Intel Atom, etc)